# Spring Webflow + MVC - Download zip file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a Spring Webflow (2.3.x) + Spring MVC portlet application that allows users to upload zip files. These zip files are stored somewhere on the filesystem of the server. I would like to now allow users to download the files via the Webflow application. The Webflow documentation contains an example that shows how to do the upload but it does not contain an example on how to allow users to download files.

Can someone provide or point me to an example that shows how to support downloads in Webflow? I'm using Thymeleaf to render my views.

Comment: if you are using spring MVC as well, then just create a request mapping in a controller to download files and use that url directly in your page, without going through webflow

Comment: I'm using this in a portlet. I'll update the question.